# Generating C++/CLI pointer type via System.CodeDom

Tags: .net, c++-cli, code-generation

I generate C++/CLI code via System.CodeDom of .NET.

Recently, I had to create a C++/CLI method with a pointer, like `int foo(char *data)` , which turned out tricky.

`System.CodeDom.CodeParameterDeclarationExpression(type, name)` creates parameters  with handles(^) only, not poiters(*) and I can't find a way to do it.

How could it be done? Any clue is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I decide to use programmatically remove asterisk from the type, create CodeTypeReference for the type without asterisk and create variable with name, starting from the asterisk.

Another way is to create "ForceTypePassThrough" key for UserData dictionary of the type as follows:

```
CodeTypeReference tmpTypeRef = new CodeTypeReference("char *");
tmpTypeRef.UserData["ForceTypePassThrough"] = true;

CodeVariableDeclarationStatement tmpVarDecl = new CodeVariableDeclarationStatement(tmpTypeRef, "tmpData");
```

This ways work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about C++/CLI pointer types in particular, but you can use [`Type.MakePointerType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makepointertype.aspx) to create a pointer type for a given non-pointer type. Have you tried using:

```
new CodeParameterDeclarationExpression(typeof(char).MakePointerType(), "data")
```

Comment: Good idea, but it creates System::Char^*, not System::Char*, which I need.

Comment: @Anton: Odd. In that case I'm out of ideas, I'm afraid. I'll leave this answer up to stop you from getting identical ones :)

Comment: An additional note: When compiling c++/cli, the keyword "char" gets compiled as System.SByte--not System.Char.  So, you'll want to be using typeof(SByte) not typeof(char).  I'm not sure about how to get the pointer type correctly though.